# Clara.io json, geometry in three js

Tags: javascript, json, three.js

I have several models in Clara.io, according to their help if you export selection, then it will be file for JSONLoader, and if you export full scene it will be file for ObjectLoader. However non of export function  working with JSONLoader (https://forum.clara.io/t/export-to-three-js-json-export-all-and-export-selected-both-export-scene-object/3709).

In my app I need only geometry from model to build Points object. So I'm looking for either methods to convert loaded object to Mesh, or some king of geometry subtraction from object itself. In helps and examples(both three and clara) I see only one action with loaded object -  `scene.add(object)`.

```
import THREE from 'three/build/three.module';
import {Scene,PerspectiveCamera,Fog,WebGLRenderer,ObjectLoader,Geometry} from 'three/build/three.module';
....
var loader = new ObjectLoader();
loader.load( 'assets/models/rabbit.json', function ( object  ) {
  //I don't need to add object here but this is the only thing that works
  //scene.add(object);
  //I need to do something like this
  geometry2 = new Geometry();
  geometry2.vertices = object.geometry.vertices; // ???
  particles = new Points( geometry2, new PointsMaterial( { color: 0xff0000, size:5 } ) );
  scene.add(particles)
});
```

Comment: Ok, updated with non working code. Not sure if it will help. The ??? comment show where I need geometry of source object.

Answer (score 0):

So clara.io seems to export single object in scene. So the way to extract mesh from it is something like:

```
loader.load( 'assets/models/rabbit.json', function ( object  ) {
  //I don't need to add object here but this is the only thing that works
  //scene.add(object);
  //I need to do something like this
  geometry2 = new Geometry();
  geometry2.vertices = object.children[0].geometry.vertices;
//object.children[0] - the first mesh in exported object
  particles = new Points( geometry2, new PointsMaterial( { color: 0xff0000, size:5 } ) );
  scene.add(particles)
});
```